# Aurelia - External Requires

Tags: aurelia

Brand new to Aurelia, and beginning to fall in love with it. I'm confused about how to include external URL's into a view however. For instance,

```
<template>
  <require from="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"></require>
  <require from="fonts/font-awesome-4/css/font-awesome.css"></require>
  <require from="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,400italic,700,800"></require>
  <require from="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,200,100"></require>
  <require from="css/style.css"></require>

  <div class="page-host">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
Evaluating http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,200,100.js
Error loading http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,200,100.js
```

Am I doing the require wrong for an external CSS or JS file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The require tag is trying to load an Aurelia ViewModel, not just doing a generic text import.

As Aurelia is a Single Page Application, it's quite possible to load the external CSS / fonts from inside your index.html using the traditional HTML methods and you will still have access to them on your other views.

If you take a look at the [skeleton app](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-esnext/index.html) that's precisely how they do it.

Comment: Worked great. Thank you so much for helping out an Aurelia noob :)

Comment: What if I want to conditionally load them only when a particular view is loaded?

Comment: It's a SPA, so you don't have a way of 'unloading' them anyway - you get no extra benefit from not loading them up front, except for maybe staggered load times.

Comment: @MichaelMalone Does this affect bundling if we load all CSS files using Links inside index.html ? I have multiple CSS files from third party shims, Is this the preferred way in aurelia ?

Comment: @user636525 If you're loading static CSS using requires, then bundling should "just work", this question was relating to dynamically loading content, so bundling shouldn't apply.